# How do I save login session and tokens from api using Preferences DataStore in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, token, datastore

So I'm just starting to learn about Preferences Datastore and Login Sessions using an Api in Kotlin. I don't know how to save the login session and tokens so that when the app is closed and I open it again, I don't have to login again. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you're stuck with using DataStore or if you're stuck with using DataStore with maintaining user session.

For the first part you can refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/preferences-datastore-in-android/, it gives you an basic idea on creating datastore, saving and retrieving data etc.

For the second part you can save a boolean value as true in datastore and as soon as the app launches, check for that value and if true treat the user as loggedIn, and also make that value false or clear the datastore on logout.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to save the login session data by saving the token of the specific user that's got from an api. Does that make sense?